# C - Problems with 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I am trying to do some kind of cartesian coordinate system to print on the command line using C. Unfortunately there are some problems when trying to insert a special character into the specified 2D array which helds the data. There are two characters which are inserted into the array during one run of the loop (the second/right row of P's):

[image]

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Part of my code which produces the problem (makeDots fills the array):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WIDTH 20
#define HEIGHT 10

void makeDots(char a[WIDTH][HEIGHT]) {
    for (int x = 4; x < 7; x++) {
        int y = x + 1;
        //cartesian coordinate system - point of origin in bottom left corner
        a[y][x] = 'P';
        //a[i-1][WIDTH / 2 + i] = '+'; //try to remove misplaced P - leads to empty array
    }
}

void clear(char a[WIDTH][HEIGHT]) {
    for (int l = 0; l < HEIGHT; l++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < WIDTH; c++) {
            a[l][c] = '+';
        }
    }
}

void draw(char a[WIDTH][HEIGHT]) {
    for (int l = HEIGHT - 1; l >= 0; l--) {
        for (int c = 0; c < WIDTH; c++) {
            putchar(a[l][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    char a[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    clear(a);
    makeDots(a);
    draw(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are getting your row and column indices mixed up. Change `[WIDTH][HEIGHT]` to `[HEIGHT][WIDTH]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed `x` and `y` in function `makeDots`, and `l`and `c` in functions `clear` and `draw`when access to array. Adapt your code like this:

```
#define WIDTH 20
#define HEIGHT 10

void makeDots(char a[WIDTH][HEIGHT]) {
    for (int x = 4; x < 7; x++) {
        int y = x + 1;
        //cartesian coordinate system - point of origin in bottom left corner
        a[x][y] = 'P';
      //  ^  ^
        //a[WIDTH / 2 + i][i-1] = '+'; //try to remove misplaced P - leads to empty array
    }
}

void clear(char a[WIDTH][HEIGHT]) {
    for (int l = 0; l < HEIGHT; l++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < WIDTH; c++) {
            a[c][l] = '+';
          //  ^  ^
        }
    }
}

void draw(char a[WIDTH][HEIGHT]) {
    for (int l = HEIGHT- 1; l >= 0; l--) {
        for (int c = 0; c < WIDTH; c++) {
            putchar(a[c][l]);
                  //  ^  ^
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    char a[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    clear(a);
    makeDots(a);
    draw(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine for me now.

Answer (score 1):

See this code of yours:

```
void clear(char a[WIDTH][HEIGHT]) {
    for (int l = 0; l < HEIGHT; l++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < WIDTH; c++) {
            a[l][c] = '+';
        }
    }
}
```

You're using [WIDTH][HEIGHT] for your char array, but in for loop, you're using the opposite. Take a look at it. That can be the problem.